# How do I configure Apache Camel to sequentially execute processes based on a trigger file?

Tags: java, apache, file, triggers, dsl

I have a situation where an external system will send me 4 different files at the same time.  Let's call them the following:

1. customers.xml (optional)
2. addresses.xml (optional)
3. references.xml (optional)
4. **activity.xml** (trigger file)

When the **trigger** file is sent and picked up by Camel, Camel should then look to see if file #1 exists, if it does then process it; if it doesn't then move on to file #2 and file #3 applying the same `if/then` logic.  Once that logic has been performed, then it can proceed with file #4.

I found elements like `OnCompletion` and determining if `body` is null or not but if someone has a much better idea, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought this further, it turns out this was more of a sequence problem.  The key here is that I would be receiving the files in batches at the same time.  That being said, I created a pluggable `CustomComparator`.

Once I created my `CustomComparator` class to order my files in a given ArrayList index position, I was able to route the messages in the order I wanted them in.

Comment: What if 1st file failed to deliver due to network glitch and immediately glitch is rectified. It will break the sequence.

Comment: It's optional, in a sense.  If it gets there before `activity.xml` then it will get processed (in sequence).  If it gets there after `activity.xml`, it will sit there until the next `activity.xml` appears.